# C# .Net Framework Disposing of Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, using

I was wondering if there are any benefits to implementing the dispose feature for Tasks.  Will this operate any different? Will this force the memory to clean up any faster?

```
Task updateTask = UpdateRemoteAsync()
await updateTask;
```

VS

```
using (Task updateTask = UpdateRemoteAsync())
{
    await updateTask;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases no, when you dispose of a `Task` you are disposing the `WaitHandle` they allocate, and according to Microsoft, Since .NET Framework 4.5 the `async/await` functionality, `WaitAll` and `WaitAny` doesn't allocate one at all unless you explicitly need to require `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle`.

Further reading: [MS Dev Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/).